# Cannot build and run the ASP.NET Boilerplate MVC 5 template

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I have recently downloaded the MVC5 ABP template, the project compiles but I get 109 warnings.  When executing the project, I get a YSOD.

- ABP v3.0.0
- .Net Framework 4.6.1
- Visual Studio 2017
- IIS 7

I get the following error message on YSOD:

`Cannot load a reference assembly for execution.`

```
[BadImageFormatException: Cannot load a reference assembly for execution.]

[BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'netfx.force.conflicts' or one of its dependencies. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131058)]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +36
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +152
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +77
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +21
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +28
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +38

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'netfx.force.conflicts' or one of its dependencies. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131058)]
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +726
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +196
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +45
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +172
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies() +91
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +111
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +156
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +677

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'netfx.force.conflicts' or one of its dependencies. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131058)]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +772
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +95
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +196
```

I get a around 60 warnings for missing references such as:

```
The referenced component 'System.Xml.XmlDocument' could not be found.
```

I get a few warnings like this:

```
Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly. Please set the "AutoGenerateBindingRedirects" property to true in the project file. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=294190.
```

And also this guy:

```
Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly. In Visual Studio, double-click this warning (or select it and press Enter) to fix the conflicts; otherwise, add the following binding redirects to the "runtime" node in the application configuration file: etc.
```

Going with VS's suggestions for resolving the conflicts...did not make any difference other than to remove the warning.

Comment: After deleting bin, I now get 81 build errors such as `The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [BadImageFormatException: Cannot load a reference assembly for execution.]

Delete the `bin` folder in the Web project and rebuild the solution.

> The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.

ABP v3.0.0 is based on .NET Standard 2.0.

- This concerns you regardless if you are on MVC 5.x, .NET Framework 4.x or .NET Core 2.x.
- You should use VS2017 15.3.3+.

Comment: Deleting the bin folder works, but the "Could not load file or assembly 'netfx.force.conflicts'" YSOD occurs again when running another console project in the solution, then relaunching the ASP project.

Comment: Seems like it'll be fixed in VS 2017.4: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/23229